# Align items in block

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="body">
  Some text
<div class="bot">some text</div>
</div>

.body{
  padding: 15px;
}
```

How to make zero padding only in element with class bot? Without adding to body another class, maybe there is some specific selectors for these purposes?

Comment: isn't `.bot{}` working?

Comment: `.bot{padding:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways one you can either remove the div with class bot from the parent div with class body like so

```
    <div class="body">
        Some text
    </div>

    <div class="bot">some text</div>
```

or 
    set the position property to absolue to the div with class .bot like so

```
.bot{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your stylesheet file

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a `<div>` is inside of another `<div>`, it is the "child" of that div. It will take those characteristics, and it acts like `padding: 0;` is padding 0 more than its parent's space.

It may be easier to write your CSS like so, to illustrate the nature of the two elements:

```
<div class="body">
  Some text
  <div class="bot">some text</div>
</div>
```

I agree with the other poster that there *is* a way to place an element in absolute position with the page, but that has the possibility to run outside of your parent element.

It seems, instead, that you are looking to place something in a part of the page that is not used by the first . It means that you probably do want to separate the two. That means you probably *don't* want to put `<div class="bot">` inside of `<div class="body">`. Instead, you want to make space for the second, lower (or higher) `<div>` inside of the parent. Perhaps like this?

```
<div class="body">
    Some text
</div>

<div class="bot">some text</div>
```

---

```
/* removes the padding from the bottom, making space for some of the div above*/
.body {
  padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
```

or this:

```
<div class="body">
    Some text
</div>

<div class="bot">some text</div>
```

---

```
.body5 {
    padding: 15px;
}

/*puts a negative margin on lower div, to make up the space*/
.bot5 {
    margin-top: -15px;
    background: green;
}
```

I've attached all of this to a CodePen if you'd like to play around with it: https://codepen.io/benjithaimmortal/pen/xMQNeJ